# Error when manually moving terraform state file and running terraform plan

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have recently been asked to take over management of VPC infrastructure on AWS. This infrastructure is currently being managed by another department; they use terraform and have configured the backend for the state file on Azure.

Since I do not have any kind of access to Azure, I asked them to share the terraform configuration code **and** send me the `terraform.tfstate` file stored in their backend.

My idea for the first few steps in taking over this project was:

1. Copy the configuration files locally and remove the part of the code
   that configures the backend to Azure (so that terraform considers a
   local file).
2. Run `terraform init`. At this point, here's a quick example of my local folder layout for the project:

```
L project
    .terraform/
    main.tf
```

3. Place the original `terraform.tfstate` inside the `.terraform` folder.
4. Run `terraform plan` and expect no changes in infrastructure.

What happens at step 4 is I get this error:

> Error: Failed to load state: Terraform 1.1.9 does not support state
> version 4, please update.

When inspecting the state file, I see `"terraform_version": "1.0.2"` which confirms that our terraform versions differ.

Note: if I instead **do not copy** that state file into the directory, then the `terraform plan` command tells me that I will be creating a bunch of new resources (as expected, as it has no state file to read from).

What is very strange though, is that if I place the `terraform.tfstate` in the root directory where I'm running my terraform commands from, so inside `project/` instead of `.terraform/`, and run `terraform plan`, I don't get the error message and terraform tells me there's nothing to update. Therefore, terraform seems to be reading the state file correctly when I place it in the incorrect location.

Could anyone help me figure out what's going on here? I don't want to proceed with `terraform apply` until I am sure I am not risking anything here.

Comment: Use `terraform state list` to make sure that terraform is reading the correct state https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/state/list or also `terraform state show <resource id>` also `terraform show` https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/show

Comment: I get the same error, no matter what command I run.

Comment: if the error is related to version, use the terraform version `1.0.2`

Answer (score 0):

> What is very strange though, is that if I place the terraform.tfstate in the root directory where I'm running my terraform commands from, so inside project/ instead of .terraform/, and run terraform plan, I don't get the error message and terraform tells me there's nothing to update. Therefore, terraform seems to be reading the state file correctly when I place it in the incorrect location.

local terraform state is correctly stored in the root folder, not inside `.terraform/` subfolder. What you're describing as incorrect location for tfstate is in fact the correct location for tfstate.